# How do you diagram Resource-Oriented Architecture (ROA)? What tools, conventions seem to work best

Tags: architecture, rest, resources

I am interested in determining if there are any effective [Resource-Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_oriented_architecture) tools or diagramming conventions that help when defining a ROA.

Comment: What do you mean with ROA? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_oriented_architecture

Answer (score 1):

[**Django's ROA diagram**](http://code.welldev.org/django-roa/wiki/Home) looks like this:

[image: Image of Django's ROA diagram]

Which you ought to be able to do with any decent UML diagramming software.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ERD (Entity Relation Diagram) to describe the Resources and its relations, then you can add supported methods on the entity in ERD itself